# How to switch branches between two separate worktrees in Git?

Tags: git, git-worktree

I added a linked working tree for "develop" branch. So my worktrees are like this:

- "project" worktree -> master branch
  - "project_develop" worktree -> develop branch

In this condition, what I want to do is to checkout master branch on "project_develop" worktree. But as I know, it is impossible to checkout same branch on separate worktrees. The only way I could think of is to add a new temporary branch. 
I would appreciate it if someone show me another way.
Thanks!

Comment: It would be useful to know what you're trying to avoid / achieve here... what is the problem you foresee with a temporary branch?

Comment: @RomainValeri there would be no problem adding a temporary branch, but the process is a bit inefficient I think, adding and deleting an extra branch just to switch existing branches. I was just wondering if there would be a better way.

Comment: I can't imagine any alternative being more "efficient" than a one line command... `git checkout <hash>` is not really quicker than `git checkout -b temp <target>`...

Comment: Do you really need it? you can merge into master.

Comment: Note that if you wish to keep an added work-tree around for a long period (more than two weeks), make sure your Git version is at least 2.15. Git versions before 2.15 (but 2.5 or later where `git worktree` first appeared) have a nasty bug where added work-trees can become corrupted after 14 days. (Exactly *when* this happens, and whether it happens at all, is not easy to predict. It has to do with a bug in `git gc`.)

Comment: @torek fortunately my git version is 2.16, thank you for the advice

Comment: @Serge This kind of system might seem a bit awkward, but it's necessary in our development environment :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is, on the `master` worktree

```
git checkout --detach
```

There are numerous other ways; the point is, since you don't have another branch to checkout to this worktree, you want to force it into detached `HEAD` state.  It can still have the same code checked out; it just can't think it's "on" the `master` branch (since there would be problems with updating the worktrees on commit).

Once that's done, on the 2nd worktree you can `git checkout master`, and then if you want you could even go back to the first worktree and `git checkout develop` to swap the branches entirely.  Or just wait until you're ready to check `develop` back to the 2nd worktree, and afterward check `master` out on the 1st tree again...

Answer (score 1):

I think creating a temporary branch is best. If you don't want to create a temporary branch, you have other options.

1. Checkout a specific commit. In your case, you can just run `git checkout refs/heads/master`. It leads to detached HEAD state. `refs/heads/master` can be replaced with the specific commit.
2. Create as many worktrees for a detached HEAD as you want to. You can run `git worktree add /path/foo1 refs/heads/master`, `git worktree add /path/foo2 refs/heads/master`, ..., `git worktree add /path/fooN refs/heads/master`.
3. Reset `develop` to `master`. In "project_develop" worktree, run `git reset master --hard`.

These approaches bypass the limitation that you can't create a second worktree for the same branch. The 1st and 2nd are nearly the same with a temporary branch. The 3rd may make you confused some time later.